# IE8 CSS after selector

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

The CSS

```
.main blockquote p:first-child:before {
    content: '“';
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 0;
}

.main blockquote p:last-child:after {
    content: '”';
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -9px;
    right: 7px;
}
```

The Code

```
<blockquote>
    <p>A quote about many wonderful things...</p>
</blockquote>
```

This works in most browsers... in IE8, I only get the before quote... what am I missing?

Comment: http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/

Comment: of course, I notice it right after I hit submit!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`last-child` does not support ie8. You have to use jquery for doing so

Answer (score 1):

The :last-child selector is not supported in IE8 and earlier versions.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp
Use some Jquery code